# HTML5/PHP. Защита от подмены пакетов

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html5, разработка-игр

У меня имеется HTML 5 игра и некоторые проблемы с защитой этой игры.

1. Предотвратить повторную отправку POST через AJAX.
2. Защита от подмены пакетов.

Сам я накатал на коленке, но получилось не очень.
Ну так вот, есть ли у кого пример или ссылки на мануалы?

Код:
config.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
include_once 'function.php';

$admin_login = '123';
$admin_password = '123';

$module_mysql = new module_mysql();
$module_db_host = 'localhost';
$module_db_name = 'n96582pg_deadfld';
$module_db_login = 'n96582pg_deadfld';
$module_db_password = '89059325694';

$module_mysql -> connect_mysql($module_db_host, $module_db_login, $module_db_password, $module_db_name);
?>
```

function.php:

```
<?php

class module_mysql {

    function connect_mysql($db_host, $db_login, $db_password, $db_name){

        mysql_connect($db_host, $db_login, $db_password, $db_name) or die ("Error connecting to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
        mysql_query("set names utf8") or die ("<br>Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("<br>Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

    }

    function query_mysql($mysql_data_query, $type, $num) {

        if ($data_query=mysql_query($mysql_data_query)) {

            switch ($type) {

                case 'num_row' : return mysql_num_rows($data_query); break;
                case 'accos' : return mysql_fetch_assoc($data_query); break;
                default: return $data_query;

            }

        } else {

            print 'MySQL error: '.mysql_error();
            return false;

        }

    }

}

class module_functions {

    function screening_function($function_data_screening) {

        $function_data_screening = htmlspecialchars(trim($function_data_screening));
        return mysql_real_escape_string($function_data_screening);

    }

    function get_hash($login, $password, $level) {

        switch($level){

            case '1' : return md5(md5($this->screening_function($login . $password)) . 'Cv7X2WVdjSGEwNFInieora45WKRxpcef');
            case '2' : return md5(sha1(md5($this->screening_function($login . $password)) . sha1('Cv7X2WVdjSGEwNFInieora45WKRxpcef')));

        }

    }

    function error_print($error) {
        $r=''."\n".'';
        foreach($error as $key=>$value) {
            $r.=''.$value."\n".'';
        }
        return $r.'';
    }

}

class module_global {

    function module_newuser($login, $password, $received_hash) {

        $module_functions = new module_functions();
        $module_mysql = new module_mysql();

        $this_hash = $module_functions->get_hash($login, $password, '1');

        if($this_hash == $received_hash){
        if(empty($login) or empty($password)) $error[] = 'All input fields are required.';
        if(strlen($login)<6 or strlen($login)>18) $error[] =  'Login length should be from 6 to 18 characters.';
        if(strlen($password)<6 or strlen($password)>20) $error[] = 'The password must be between 6 and 20 characters.';
        $login = $module_functions->screening_function($login);
        if($module_mysql->query_mysql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login_user='".$login."';", 'num_row', '')!=0) $error[] = 'A user with this name already exists.';  else return 'good';
        } else $error[] = 'Invalid hash.';

        if(isset($error)) return $module_functions->error_print($error);

    }

    function module_auth($login, $password, $received_hash) {

        $module_functions = new module_functions();
        $module_mysql = new module_mysql();

        $this_hash = $module_functions->get_hash($login, $password, '1');

        if($this_hash == $received_hash){

            if(!empty($login) or !empty($password)){

                $password = md5(md5($module_functions->screening_function($password)) . 'Cv7X2WVdjSGEwNFInieora45WKRxpcef');
                $login = $module_functions->screening_function($login);

                if ($module_mysql->query_mysql("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE  `login_user` =  '".$login."' AND  `password_user` = '".$password."';", 'num_row', '')==1) {

                    print md5($this_hash . 'Cv7X2WVdjSGEwNFInieora45WKRxpcef' . $this_hash) . ' | ';
                    return true;

                } elseif($module_mysql->query_mysql("SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE  `login_user` =  '".$login."';", 'num_row', 0)==1) {

                    $error[] = 'You did not enter the correct password.';

                } else $error[] = 'User does not exist.';

            } else $error[] = 'Enter data.'; 

        } else $error[] = 'Invalid hash.'; 

        if (isset($error)) print $module_functions->error_print($error); return false;

    }


    function module_reg($login, $password, $received_hash){

        $module_functions = new module_functions();
        $module_mysql = new module_mysql();

        if (($this->module_newuser($login, $password, $received_hash)) == 'good') {

                $password = md5(md5($module_functions->screening_function($password)) . 'Cv7X2WVdjSGEwNFInieora45WKRxpcef');
                $login = $module_functions->screening_function($login);

                if ($module_mysql->query_mysql("INSERT INTO `users` (`id_user`, `login_user`, `password_user`) VALUES (NULL, '".$login."', '".$password."');", '', '')) {

                    print md5($this_hash . 'Cv7X2WVdjSGEwNFInieora45WKRxpcef' . $this_hash) . ' | ';
                    return true;

                } else {

                print 'An error occurred while registering a new user. Please contact the property'; return false;

                }

        } else print $this->module_newuser($login, $password, $received_hash); return false;

    }

}

?>
```

function_ajax.php:

```
<?php

include_once 'config.php';

$module_global = new module_global(); 

if(isset($_POST['type']) && isset($_POST['login']) && 

isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['hash'])){

switch($_POST['type']){

    case 'module_auth' : 
    if ($module_global->module_auth($_POST['login'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['hash'])) {
        echo 'true'; break;
    } else {
        echo 'false'; break;
    }

    case 'module_reg' :
    if ($module_global->module_reg($_POST['login'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['hash'])) {
        echo 'true'; break;
    } else {
        echo 'false'; break;
    }

}

} else print 'PHP error: invalid data';


?>
```

Comment: Как, если не секрет?

Comment: По вашему вопросу: просто надо все делать на стороне сервера, это затратно, но ничего не поделать, у клиента только ключ(по которому он общается с вашим сервером) - ключ, можно обезопасить, на это 300 способов есть, и манипулирует(обычно визуально) с данными которые принимает. Надо понимать все что вы принимаете - небезопасно. Поэтому лучше пусть все делает сервер.

Comment: Все важные данные надо проверять на серверной стороне. Тратят игровые деньги - проверяйте, есть ли они на счету, или не потрачены ли ранее.

Comment: У меня была мысль, чтобы записывать все операции в бд, но не клеится с моим "конструктором".

Comment: С чем не клеится?

Comment: Смотрите, я отправляю данные на сервер и он проверяет верные они или нет, если данные верные то отправляет "true", если нет то "false". Это я про регистрация и авторизацию, если что)

Comment: Без кода, сложно, что либо сказать. Как отправляете, что делаете, ничего не понятно и не видно пакетку. Оформите в свой вопрос - код который отвечает за отправку пакетов и то, где происходит получение пакетов и что выполняется после их поучения.

Comment: Обычная аутентификация. Посылаются PoST данные -> проверка БД -> true - false. Когда буду за компьютером, покажу php.

Comment: А что за игра? Можете дать ссылочку?

Comment: Игра еще даже не связана с сервером, поэтому ссылки нет.
Код писал не я, если что.